# Generate all bit patterns for a given mask

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, bit-manipulation

My problem is as follows: I have a value `x` and a pattern `p` both variables of the same size. The goal is to iterate through all bit patterns of x that are *not* masked by p.

Example:
if we have `p = 1001`, we want to find `0000`, `0001`, `1000`, and `1001` - not necessarily in that order.

Standard implementation in C99 (the return value specifies whether we have returned all values already):

```
static bool next(size_t val, size_t mask, size_t *out) {
    if (val == mask) {
        return false;
    }
    size_t current = val & mask;
    size_t inc = 1;
    size_t new_val = current + inc;
    while ((new_val & mask) <= current) {
        inc++;
        new_val = current + inc;
    }
    *out = new_val;
    return true;
}
```

I would think there should be some trick to make this more efficient, but I can't seem to find any big improvements (apart from computing the trailing zeros of the mask and setting the start value of inc appropriately, which isn't much of an improvement).

Edit: Also important is the fact that for each generated value lots of additional work is generated, which means that lots of duplicates are out of the question (some duplicates, even if not recognizable would be ok, there aren't any side effects to the work done, it's just a slowdown).

Comment: What's wrong with generating all the binary numbers and masking them appropriately with `p`?

Comment: @H2CO3 Ah I should've mentioned that the work done on the given numbers is rather expensive, so generating lots of duplicates is not acceptable. Will update the post to include that part - stupid of me to ignore such an important factor. Otherwise seems to me that the proposed approach is equivalent to the current one wrt the work done.

Comment: @H2CO3 if set bits are few, given that size_t may be 64 bit that would be very inefficient.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This generates all bit patterns in reverse order (initial value of `val` should be equal to `mask`):

```
static bool next(size_t val, size_t mask, size_t *out) {
    if (val == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    *out = (val - 1) & mask;
    return true;
}
```

---

And this (slightly less obvious code) generates all bit patterns in direct order (initial value of `val` should be zero):

```
static bool next(size_t val, size_t mask, size_t *out) {
    if (val == mask) {
        return false;
    }

    *out = (val - mask) & mask;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Wow. Really nice and simple. +1.

Comment: Doesn't this generate duplicates?

Comment: @Paolo: no, each pattern is generated exactly once.

Comment: Wow a O(1) solution in less than halve the code. I'm deeply impressed.. also slightly embarrassed that I didn't come up with this myself, but as always: Simple ain't easy. I hope I won't forget to give you an extra +100 rep or so in 2 days.

Comment: @Evgeny I really didn't believe. So I tried. And it works! +1

Comment: This works because 1) the value of the number is strictly decreasing (due to minus and `&` operation) 2) the `- 1` will make parts of the `val` corresponding to the 1 bits reduce by 1 (like when you extract out those bits and compress them together, then `- 1`). The `&` part will zero out the parts we don't care about, so that the propagation done by `- 1` works as above.

Answer (score 1):

From your example, it looks like this pseudo-code will do the trick:

```
current = p // set up current
getNotMasked(p, 0) // initial call


bitString current

getNotMasked(int pos)
  if (pos == current.length)
    print(current)
    return
  if (current[pos] == 1)
    current[pos] = 0
    getNotMasked(pos+1)
    current[pos] = 1
    getNotMasked(pos+1)
  else
    getNotMasked(pos+1)
```

Generating C code from here shouldn't be difficult - replace `bitString` with `int` and `[pos]` with `& 1 << pos` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The most optimal way feels like:

1. Count the number of set bits in the mask, p
2. Figure out a way to shuffle bits from a "normalized" binary value into the position decided by the pattern
3. Count through 0..2<sup>p</sup>-1
4. For each value shuffle to generate pattern-compatible value

This of course assumes that doing the shuffling is reasonably efficient, otherwise it's easier to brute-force it by just counting from 0 to the largest possible value depending on the *total* number of bits in the pattern, and applying the pattern at each count. Detecting duplicates might be a bit expensive, though.

For `p = 9` (binary 1001<sub>2</sub>), there are just two bits set, so we know there are 2<sup>2</sup> = 4 values to generate.

Scanning the pattern from the right for 1-bits, we can form the following "shuffling table":

- Bit 0 is copied from bit 0
- Bit 3 is copied from bit 1

So, we can count from 0 to 3, and for each value rearrange according to the table:

- 00<sub>2</sub> gives output 0000<sub>2</sub>
- 01<sub>2</sub> gives output 0001<sub>2</sub>
- 10<sub>2</sub> gives output 1000<sub>2</sub>
- 11<sub>2</sub> gives output 1001<sub>2</sub>